# Mold, Lead, Asbestos Testing Kits - recommended or seek a professional?

Tags: mold, asbestos, testing, lead

Professional testing of Mold or Lead or Asbestos can range from $300 - $1000 for each type.
I just found some home testing kits that require you to take and submit samples.

Are these a good cost savings approach with adequate results or should I consult professionals?

UPDATE

I actually found this on the EPA website.
[EPA Accredited laboratories.](https://www-s.nist.gov/niws/index.cfm?event=directory.search#no-back)
You can just send samples in ziplock baggies to these laboratories for testing.  I saw that a lot of the DIY kits out there are essentially just baggies! So no need to buy those kits.

Comment: Reasoned advice on mold is available from the feds (eg, https://www.epa.gov/mold/mold-cleanup-your-home). Mold removal companies tend to be alarmists and even uninformed.  What makes you think you need to test for mold?

Comment: I see some water damage in our garage...the bottom part of some walls...  I know that there are some asbestos vent pipes in the attic based on internet research of transite flue pipes. We live in a house that is built in 1939 so there's probably lead paint.

Answer (score 1):

Seems reasonable to me.  IMO, if you are able to send samples to a lab, that is going to be more precise and certain than any kit you could apply in the field.

The only thing I don't like about it is that it creates a third-party record, which means now you must engage any formalities of dealing with those things, and the formalities can be more annoying and expensive than the actual work.

Comment: This is the kit: https://certifiedkit.com/product/lead-mold-and-asbestos-testing-kit/. There is the Chain of Custody included with the kit. Is that the formalities that you're talking about?

Comment: No, I'm talking about what the government might require to clean them up.

Comment: To clean up after the positive detection?